# In Python Colab Google, How to upload (read) some or several files (gif) from DRIVE

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

How to import several images (around 60) from DRIVE  in order to read them with Python Colab?. I want to read them in order to compare them

In my search, I follow this treat but it is for just one file.
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=XDg9OBaYqRMd

In my try, I made this code
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hVKMd1xdiUq4Lx4MFt-zbBH5DetaqGI7?usp=sharing

```
from google.colab import drive   #1/ Montar datos desde Drive, con autorizacion
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

change to directory where the files are place

```
!cd /content/drive/My\ Drive/cursos\ imagenes/
```

and then I process the image, but
how to import the 60 images?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image
#Open the image
image0 = Image.open('0.gif')
image = Image.open('20.gif')
plt.imshow(image)
```

I aprecciate any help, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find a way, but I got error in my code
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hVKMd1xdiUq4Lx4MFt-zbBH5DetaqGI7?usp=sharing

```
 #Goal, read multiple files from Drive

# Thanks to  https://github.com/ruelj2/Google_drive

!pip install - U - q PyDrive  
import os  
os.chdir('/content/')  

# in order to clone the instruction of Google_drive
!git clone https://github.com/ruelj2/Google_drive.git  

from Google_drive.handle import *
Gd = Google_drive()  
  
#This is a Google directory link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TcMSKVAgRXZXymxfBv3WouPkauSIIpDX  
#local_file = 'path/to/local/file'
#drive_dir_ID = '1TcMSKVAgRXZXymxfBv3WouPkauSIIpDX' 

# in my case
# https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PTiDDildDxCvMr_rutu-xDgQxmb7bs0u

#local_file = 'path/to/local/file'
drive_dir_ID = '1PTiDDildDxCvMr_rutu-xDgQxmb7bs0u' 
drive_dir = '/content/drive/a enes/transito'

# Read all files
Gd.load_all(drive_dir, drive_dir_ID)  
#Read a single file
#Gd.load_version(local_file, drive_dir_ID)
```

Any help I aprecciate